# Synchronisation JAVA - File lock

Tags: java, file, synchronization

I have the following code , it is a part of a multi thread server code :

```
 File ff=new File("../key.txt");
       if(ff.exists())
         {
            try(
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("..\key.txt"))) {



                for(String line2; (line2 = br.readLine()) != null; ) {


                    System.out.println("WE ARE READING 'KEY' ");
                    String a[]=line2.split("-");
                    k[i2]=a[0];
                    od[i2]=a[1];
                    ed[i2]=a[2];
                    System.out.println("key: "+k[i2]+" OD: "+od[i2]+" ED: "+ed[i2]);
                                                                      }
                                                                                }
         }
```

i've read about "synchronisation" in java but i didn't guess how to integrate it in my code, i want to lock the file "key" whenever a user is using it so another user at the same time cannot access it if someone else is already using it (for security reasons), any ideas ?

Comment: Offtopic: `FF` variable should be called `ff`. By convention variables and methods starts with lower case and classes or interfaces starts with upper case. The variable `ff` may be used to create `FileReader` instead of typing the same path twice.

Comment: @user270349 i know , its just a test code

Comment: In that case you want file locking, not synchronization (search for java file lock on stack overflow and you'll get plenty of examples). But a better question would be why multiple users within one server would _ever_ share the same file. That's a bad idea. Consider using session-specific files instead (see File.createTmpFile or such).

Comment: @user1676075 : good question , because the file is used like a database, and i don't want to use one because i don't want to enter in sql integration

Comment: You might then consider Derby (Java embedded SQL DB). It's light-weight, embedded, multi-threaded, and included with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not used in other place but this code you may just synchronize the block:

```
synchronized {
   File ff=new File("../key.txt");
   if(ff.exists()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ff))) {
        try(
           // YOUR STUFF WITH br HERE
        } finally {
           br.close();
        }

     }
 }
```

If the file is shared between several parts of the code you may want to use a constant monitor to synchronize against it (`synchronized (MY_MONITOR_OBJECT) {...}`) or use a lock ([doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)).